# articles and relative clauses

Tags: articles, relative-clauses

I want to test my understanding of articles with relative clauses.

1. He's already lost **a phone** he bought last week.

   - Only **one** phone had been bought. Listener **doesn't** know the phone.
2. He's already lost **the phone** he bought last week.

   - Only **one** phone had been bought. Listener **knows** the phone.
3. He's already lost **the phones** he bought last week.

   - **Many** phones had been bought. Listener **knows** the phones.
4. He's already lost **phones** he bought last week.

   - **Many** phones had been bought. Listener **doesn't** know the phones.
5. He's already lost **one of the phones** he bought last week.

   - **Many** phones had been bought. Listener **knows** the phones.
6. He's already lost **one of phones** he bought last week.

   - **Many** phones had been bought. Listener **doesn't** know the phones.

Are these correct? I doubt the last one.

UPDATE: Why has this question been closed as off-topic? I have difficulty in understanding the articles and relative clauses, so I formed my question in my own way. Should I attend any university to learn to ask the question the way moderators approve? Is this not learner's forum?

Comment: Unless this is police-speak shorthand etc. Listener knows the phone is not grammatical in English. Fyi, we don't do corrections here. Please read the Help file on the top right of your screen under English Language Learners.

Comment: The choice of article in #1 and #2 doesn't really have anything to do with whether addressee knows anything at all about the lost phone. Addressee knows for sure "he" (the person being talked about) *did actually buy a phone*, because that's in the statement. But he doesn't necessarily know anything else. If speaker had said *He's already lost **that** phone he bought last week,* this would strongly imply the speaker (and *probably* also the addressee) know *something* about that act of purchasing and/or the specific phone purchased. But that's not true with ***the** phone* in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for pointing out **that** vs **this**, which have deepened my understating of this topic.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for the FYI, but this is not a question asked for correction. I had had lots of confusions related to *articles and relative clauses*, and I formulated my doubts in this way, not copied from anywhere but I prepared myself.

Comment: I correct English mistakes that come up in questions. We say: I was very confused about and not confusions.

Comment: Why has this question been closed as off-topic? I have difficulty in understanding the articles and relative clauses, so I formed my question in my own way. Should I attend any university to learn to ask the question the way moderators approve? Is this not learner's forum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the statements gives any information about the listener's knowledge or otherwise of the phone(s) other than inferring their probable existence from what is said.

Ignoring the statements about knowledge:

1. He could have bought one phone or many phones - you cannot tell.
2. Correct
3. Correct
4. Correct
5. Correct
6. Incorrect grammar, the word "the" cannot be omitted from 5.

**Many** in these examples means more than one.

Comment: if the listener's knowledge cannot be in any of those statements,  what is the difference between 3rd and 4th sentences?

Comment: @Englishified You can infer from 3 that he lost **all** the phones whilst 4 implies he lost **some of the** phones. He may not have lost them all.